# How do I build an 'embeddable widget'?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3

My webapp uses both Rails and JS and I would like users to be able to embed the images they upload to any blog/site.

What do I need to know, from a development point-of-view to allow me to create the functionality that generates an 'embed' link. It can be either a link like YouTube does, or a JS snippet or anything.

Just want to get a high-level overview of what I need to be able to do and how to proceed.

Thanks.

Comment: Not going to write a full answer because I'm not sure if I fully understand this question, but couldn't you just write a helper method which generates some markup?

Comment: Well...i meant in terms of how it would work. But Jacob answered nicely re the iframe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would try using iframe. I created a widget which used javascript and I put it all into a single html file hosted on my website. Then I gave away an iframe snippet like this for example...

```
<iframe src="http://mywesbite.com/myWidget.html"></iframe>
```

The user can simply place the iframe snippet into their website and that's it!

Comment: ahh...this actually makes sense. So I guess I have to make Rails render as html or something of the sort. This makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome! I once tried to create a widget using embed but i'm pretty sure I figured out soon enough that embed is only for plugins such as flash which is why youtube has embed tags. Actually, I just checked youtube, and guess what! They use iframe tags now. Check out any youtube video, press share, then embed and it shows iframe code!

Comment: That's interesting...so literally all I have to do is make sure that the generated html is publicly accessible, and I am good to go. This is definitely interesting.

Comment: Exactly. I put it on my website ftp server. But i also tried this, I uploaded the html file to a file sharing site called Dropbox, and i put the src of the iframe code, to the share link that dropbox provides. This was just another option, however i went back to the first way (on my website server) because Dropbox has a bandwidth restriction which was a lot less that my websites bandwidth one, and for that reason i switched back. But it was interesting to know that an iframe can link to a file on Dropbox, and probably other file sharing sites as well. Anyways good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little bit late to the party here, but I just wanted to add to Jacob's answer.

You can easily allow the user to customize the embedded content (perhaps choose light on dark vs. dark on light text to more closely match the page's environment/design) by using query params within the iframe src:

```
<iframe src="http://___.com/widget?theme=light&size=large"></iframe>
```

of course you'd probably want to build a UI to allow the user to make these distinct changes... you can't expect average user's to do that by hand:)

Vimeo's UI for customizing embedded videos is pretty nice if you want a best case scenario.